# Timestamp not working

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to know the time and date everytime a new entry is saved in my database. So i set the column as follows:

[image]

The problem is that im just geting 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as the date/time:

[image]

The code that im using to update the database is:

```
<?php

$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lon = $_GET['lon'];
$fecha = $_GET['fecha'];

// Make a MySQL Connection

$db_database = "xxx";
$db_hostname = "xxx";
$db_username = "xxx";
$db_password = "xxx";


$enlace = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$enlace) {
    die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Conectado satisfactoriamente. <br>';
// mysql_close($enlace);


mysql_select_db('xxxxx') or die(mysql_error());


$q = "INSERT INTO `posicion` (`Hora`, `Latitud`, `Longitud`) VALUES 
 ('$fecha', '$lat','$lon')";

//Run Query
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

echo "Tamos redi";

?>
```

What can it be ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you inserting data?

Comment: calling a .php file from the server:
http://www.example.com/update.php?lat=x&lon=y

Comment: Can you show us your PHP script that inserts the data

Comment: Need to see the query that is inserting the data.  You should be able to pass `null` as the value and MySQL will take it from there.

Comment: Question edited with the code!

Comment: Replace `$fetcha` with `null` in your query and MySQL will update the timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the default value for `Hora` is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you can just rely on MySQL to fill it in.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `posicion` (`Hora`, `Latitud`, `Longitud`) VALUES 
 (NULL, '$lat','$lon')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alter table <INSERT TABLENAME> modify <Hora> TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and reffer:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html